# jQuery - select an element that contains a specific value

Tags: jquery, select

I need to do something sort of backwards here.

I'm using the following to disable a value in a dropdown, which works fine.

```
$('*[id^="dd"] option[value=' + info.products_options_values_id_affected + ']').attr("disabled",vOut);
```

The problem is, if the user selected this option before it was disabled, it needs to reset the dropdown to its default(top) value. The problem is, all of the html is dynamically generated, and I don't know which dropdown contains the value being acted on.

Every value in every dropdown has a unique id, so what I'm hoping to do is determine which dropdown contains an entry with the same **value**, not text, as the one selected by the code above, and reset it back to its top value. Is it possible to do a select in this way?

Thanks!

EDIT: Here's a sample of the generated html I'm working on:

```
<select name="id[11]" onchange="edComboFunc(11)" id="dd11">
    <option value="16">Choose Here</option>
    <option value="15">Color Changing</option>
    <option value="14">Amber</option>
    <option value="13">Blue</option>
    <option value="12">Green</option>
    <option value="20">White</option>
    <option value="21">Purple</option>
    <option value="22">Turquoise</option>
    <option value="27">Orange</option>
    <option value="11">Red</option>
    <option value="23">Pink</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but if I understood your question correctly this is what you're trying to do? If not, let me know please.

```
$("option[value*='23']").parent("select");
```

Comment: Yes, you're on the right track, but I'm getting 'undefined' when getting the id:

    var myEl = $('input[value="' + myValue + '"]').attr('id');

Comment: @user2255896 Let me try to work out a jsFiddle for you, I'll get back to you in a few minutes. (Actually) could you set up the initial HTML so I can see what you're working with?

Comment: I edited the op with a sample of the dynamically generated select code, hope that helps some. Thanks again for your time on this.

Comment: @user2255896 So you would want the `option` with `value=11` because the `id` is `['11']` right?

Comment: I don't understand your last question. The goal I'm after is the id of the dropdown itself, not any of its options. At the time the function is run, the only info I have to work with is that the value 23 (pink) is going to be disabled. I need to figure out which dropdown contains value 23, and it needs to be returned to its default, or top option. It's an oddball way of going about it, and the problem could be solved by changing other code, but I was hoping for a simple solution, as jquery usually provides :)

Comment: @user2255896 Thanks for the clarification - why not do something like this then?

`$("option[value*='23']").parent("select");`

Comment: There we go, that's exactly what I needed. Thank you!!

Comment: why not `$("option[value='" + myValue "']").parent()`

Comment: @ArunPJohny That's what I have

Comment: @user2255896 If this solves your issue please mark the answer to close the question. If not, I'm glad to keep helping

Comment: I did mark your first answer as correct, however that one really wasn't the one that was correct. Maybe you want to edit that answer to show:
    `$("option[value*='23']").parent("select");`
as the correct answer.

And again, thank you!

Comment: @user2255896 Isn't that what's up there now? The only difference is I use `myValue` in place of `23` so it works dynamically. Also, I'll remove the first line to avoid confusion